# JNI custom exceptions with more than one parameter

Tags: java, android, c++, exception, java-native-interface

I am fairly new to JNI goodness so please just tell me if I am being stupid.

I am trying to throw a custom exception from C++ to the Java layer that gets constructed with both a string and an integer.
I can't get ThrowNew() to work because It only takes one string parameter.  EVERY example of a custom exception that I could find uses ThrowNew()!! Grrrrrr

I am guessing that I will need to costruct one with  and throw it with "Throw(jthrowable obj)" but I am not sure.. is that the same as "ThrowNew()"??

For example, this is what I need:

```
int myErrorCode = 42;
const char* myErrorString = "stuff broke";

jclass myExceptionClass = env->FindClass("MyException");
env->ThrowNew(myExceptionClass, myErrorString, myErrorCode );//<-- of course this wont work!
```

This code works fine if my exception class looks like Exception() and takes only a String.

Does anyone know how to construct and throw a NEW instance of an exception to java that takes parameters other than Exception()'s default string?
Throwing only a string is worthless to me.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use [`env->Throw`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/jni/spec/functions.html#wp5234) to throw an instance you create manually:

```
jclass myExceptionClass = env->FindClass("MyException");
jstring myErrorJString = env->NewStringUTF(myErrorString);
jmethodID ctorMethod = env->GetMethodID(myExceptionClass, "<init>", "(Ljava/lang/String;I)V");
jobject myExceptionObject = env->NewObject(myExceptionClass, ctorMethod, myErrorJString, myErrorCode);
env->Throw(myExceptionObject);
```

Comment: Thank you SO much!  I have never done this from JNI and I wasn't sure if that would leak. :^)

Comment: No problem! And JNI knows it's an object reference and treats it like any other object reference. You're all good.